# How to reuse connection across multiple HTTP requests with Net::HTTP?

Tags: ruby, connection, net-http

[The documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.5/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/Net/HTTP.html) says:

> If you wish to re-use a connection across multiple HTTP requests without automatically closing it you can use ::new instead of ::start. request will automatically open a connection to the server if one is not currently open. You can manually close the connection with finish.

But it's `::start` that seems like a way of reusing a connection, isn't it? Additionally, how can I check if connection is open or still open?